# SQLite Browser without SQLCipher support in Ubuntu

Tags: sqlite, ubuntu, sqlcipher, sqlite-browser

SQLite Browser package for ubuntu does not come with SQLCipher by default.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser
```

## The Question

How could it be enabled in order to be able to view encrypted databases?

## What Versions

- Ubuntu 17.10
- SQLite Browser 3.10.99
- Qt 5.9.1
- SQLite 3.19.3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update

https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/blob/master/BUILDING.md#ubuntu--debian-linux

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential git cmake libsqlite3-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools\
    qttools5-dev-tools libsqlcipher-dev qtbase5-dev libqt5scintilla2-dev libqcustomplot-dev\
    qttools5-dev
$ git clone https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser
$ cd sqlitebrowser
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -Dsqlcipher=1 -Wno-dev ..
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

---

### Legacy

The solution is to build SQLite Browser with `libsqlcipher-dev` package.

Here the steps required:

1. First install the `libsqlcipher-dev` package.

```bash
sudo apt-get install libsqlcipher-dev
```

2. Then install requisites for building SQLite Browser.

```bash
sudo apt install build-essential git cmake libsqlite3-dev \
                   qt5-default qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools
```

3. Clone repository.

```bash
git clone https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser
```

4. Build steps:

```bash
cd sqlitebrowser
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -Dsqlcipher=1 -Wno-dev ..
make
sudo make install
```

This should complete without errors, giving you a binary file called `sqlitebrowser` which has now SQLCipher support.

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 you also need to install qttools5-dev

Comment: Perfect! Although I really needed the qttools5-dev in my Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This solution also works with Ubuntu 20.04. You must have installed qttools5-dev

Comment: For those who can find it useful, I put the build in my personal ppa: https://launchpad.net/~igor-cali/+archive/ubuntu/igisw-stable